# Changing boolean value when clicking g.drawString() in Java

Tags: java

I want to try to switch a boolean value when a certain string is clicked. 
For example:

```
boolean storeIsOpen = false;  

g.drawString("Store is closed. Click to open", x, x);
```

When that is clicked, `storeIsOpen` should turn true, and the text should be:

```
g.drawString("Store is open. Click to close", x, x);
```

How would I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

a simple solution would be you would draw that text on a button (instead of drawing directly)... You can add an ActionListener on the button and react on this event (e.g. toggle boolean state and redraw image) or trigger actions imidiately...

another solution (if you prefer to draw directly) would be to add an MouseListener on your panel (the panel onto you actually draw) and check if your click is within certain bounds (within the bounds of the string for example). When it's inside do the same as mentioned above (toggle the boolean state, redraw the panel or whatever)...